# Is Paypal the normal way that Facebook apps accept payment?

Tags: facebook, paypal

This might be a very basic and clueless question, but while I understand that there are apps and games on Facebook that seem to make money (Farmville?), since I use them infrequently, I'm vague on how they operate in general.

Is there a normal, standard way of handling payment on Facebook? Or is it a "whatever works" situation like most of the rest of the web?

Is it Paypal? Is there a variety of options?

If someone were to build an app for use within Facebook, what payment method should they be considering? Are there different technical considerations depending on the type of app?

Comment: Facebook use their own credits system, that is the only way any application can accept payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook have their own payments system, which is mandatory for games on facebook.com which are accepting payments, see here: http://developers.facebook.com/credits for more details

Comment: The documentation is not clear if that's just for games, or for other apps. My app isn't a game, so I'm still a bit in the dark.

Comment: It's mandatory for games, optional for other apps on facebook